# Evaluating $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{\cosh (z) -1}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{\cosh (z) -1}dz$ where $\gamma$ is the positively oriented boundary of $\{x+iy \in \Bbb{C} : y^2 < (4\pi^2 -1)(1-x^2)\}$.

I just learned the residue theorem, so I assume I have to apply that here.
My trouble is that the integrad $h(z)=\frac{z}{\cosh (z) -1}$ has infinitely many isolated singularities, namely $\{2\pi i n: n\in \Bbb{Z}\}$. I also have no intuition for the path $\gamma$.

I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rewrite the domain in more familiar form,

$$\{ x+iy \in \mathbb{C} : (4\pi^2-1)\cdot x^2 + y^2 < 4\pi^2-1\} = \biggl\{ x + iy \in \mathbb{C} : x^2 + \biggl(\frac{y}{\sqrt{4\pi^2-1}}\biggr)^2 < 1\biggr\}.$$

In that form, it is not too difficult to see what the domain is, and hence what $\gamma$ is. Then you just need to find the singularities of $\frac{z}{\cosh z - 1}$ in the domain.

Comment: So we can choose as domain $D$ the open unit disk. Then $\gamma$ is a null-homotopic path in $D$ and the only singularity of $h$ in the domain is the origin. Then by the residue theorem $\int_{\gamma} h d\xi = \text{res} (h,0)$, right? Further, I've computed  $\text{res} (h,0)=2$. Is that correct?

Comment: No, we can't choose the open unit disk as domain. We are given the domain whose boundary is the path of integration. That domain is a proper superset of the open unit disk. It is a geometrically simple domain, however, and it is easy to see which singularities lie in that domain. The residue you computed at $0$ is correct.

Comment: Right, it's an ellipse and the only singularity that lies in it is the origin. However, I don't quite follow what you said in the beginning. I'm applying this version of the residue theorem (from Remmert): http://i.imgur.com/RH5Lisx.png Can't we choose $D$ to be any domain which contains $\gamma$ such that $0$ is the only singularity of $h$ in $D$?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas Yes, but $\gamma$ is not contained in the open unit disk. The ellipse has semiaxes $1$ and $\sqrt{4\pi^2-1} \approx 6.2$. We could choose the disk with centre $0$ and radius $2\pi$ for example. But you don't need to choose a domain $D$ explicitly, the integrand is an entire meromorphic function, so all that matters is that $\gamma$ doesn't pass through any poles, and which poles are enclosed by $\gamma$.